# Can I use a websocket connection within a serviceworker to receive notifications while my PWA is closed?

Tags: websocket, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I was wondering whether it is possible to host a websocket connection within the boundaries of a `serviceworker.js` in order to receive notifications while my PWA is closed.

Given the documentation, the regular Push API is the proposed and go-to solution here, but I'm interested whether this is also possible via WebSockets, because my application would be way nicer to work with due to existing libraries for the programming language I use.

Also, websockets would give me an easy way of knowing whether or when my users are online / offline.

So, is this possible in a serviceworker.js, or would it lose the connection under certain circumstances?

Comment: No, web sockets require the browser to be open. Plus service workers do not intercept web socket traffic. A lot are confused about this. Service workers only handle HTTPS network requests.
External events to trigger a service worker right now are push, sync and periodic sync. None of which iPhones support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

The service worker is a somehow a thread  of a web page. A web page (usually) lives in a tab of a browser (a PWA is also managed by a browser engine). Nowadays browsers are gearing towards performance and a lower memory footprint (think mobile). So the browser will kill (or sleep) your page as soon as it thinks it can because you're not using a page you're not viewing. Yes, a WebSocket will give you some priority against normal pages, but not that much.

Then there is the OS running the browser. Its main mission is to manage resources, like CPU cycles and RAM memory. And yes, it'll also try to kill you sooner than later.

Comment: So it's basically web push as the mainly supported library or I'm out of luck?

Comment: In order to receive notifications I would say yes, use the Push API. You can still use websockets to get other benefits

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, I appreciate it. I'll probably go with Push API first, see how it behaves, and potentially combine both technologies if I'm not satisfied